# Does a node contain this value? boolean contains(double val) method

Tags: java, nodes, boolean-operations

I'am trying to make this boolean method return true/false if any node in a list contains the value the user inputs.
Everything compiles but when I run the method in the test class, it crashes.Any ideas?

```
public boolean contains(double info)
{
  Node t = root;
  int count = 0;
  while(t != null)
  {
     if(t.val == info)
     {
        count++;
        t = t.next;
     }
  }
  if(count > 0)
  {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

public class Tester
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();   
            System.out.println( list );

            list.add(100);
            list.add(104);
            list.add(108);
            list.add(107);
            System.out.println( list );
            System.out.println(" The size of the list is: " + list.size() );
            System.out.println( list );

            System.out.print(list.contains(102));
  }
}
```

Comment: Give more info than that. What is the error? What are the contents of the list?

Comment: It doesnt give me an error message, the code just simply doesn't run. After applying the method, the program just stops running and I have to end it.

Comment: You have an infinite loop here if `root.val != info`.

Comment: I'm guessing that the body of your `while` loop should be just `if(t.val == info) { return true; } t = t.next;`

Comment: If you use your debugger to step through the code, you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not handle the case that the root node has the correct value. The method body should be refactored like this:

```
Node t = root;
while(t != null){
    if(t.val == info){
        return true;
    }
    t = t.next;
}
return false;
```

Comment: @EdwardLavaire no problem